# Is "geometry" plural or singular?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

Which one of the following sentences is correct?

> The geometry of the objects are known.
>
> The geometry of the objects is known.

Both cases are common in the literature and have been used interchangebly!

Comment: Considering [the word has the plural "geometries"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/geometry) I would think it would have to be singular.

Comment: geometry of objects is/geometry of objects are :https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=geometry+of+objects+is%2C+geometry+of+objects+are&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgeometry%20of%20objects%20is%3B%2Cc0

Comment: "geometry of objects are" gives more search results than "geometry of objects is" in google web search, and it is also more abundant in Google Scholar.

Comment: @Aydin - can you show your Ngram search please, mine is just the opposite!!

Comment: If you're counting hits for Google search, the results are meaningless. Especially since the pages returned for *"are"* include things like *"Characteristics of the geometry of objects are", "Operations that change the geometry of objects are", " the location, function, and geometry of objects are".*

Comment: I would like to see some concrete examples of the plural use in the literature.

Comment: @Josh61, I was using web and scholar search in google.

Comment: @Peter, You are right, such counts are meaningless as I see now.

Comment: @painfulenglish, The literature that I am referring to is the scientific literature. I am writing a scientific paper. You can find many such examples in google scholar. E.g. "In these models, first, 3D geometry of objects are described", "The geometry of objects are also independent between objects.", ...

Comment: @Aydin Are you sure that these are not just poorly written papers?

Comment: @painfulenglish, I am asking here to make sure that these are just poorly written!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Geometry is **singular** and should be followed by **a singular verb** ("is", "has")

**geometry** - noun, pl. **geometries**.

The mathematics of the properties, measurement, and relationships of points, lines, angles, surfaces, and solids. [The Free Dictionary.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/geometry)

> geometries - pl.
>
> - *"Three geometries were used to show this effect."*
> - *"These geometries were chosen because they maximize detection capability."*

Comment: If plural form exists, shouldn't we say "geometries of objects" instead of "geometry of objects"? It seems that geometry is uncountable in most cases and may be used to mean geometries.

Comment: @Aydin, *Geometries* refers to multiple different systems, or sometimes multiple different sets of points or shapes.  In this case, "The geometry of the objects is known" means that the particular arrangement of those objects, or the characteristics in regards to their shape/configuration, is known - so it should be singular if they have a single arrangement or configuration.  However if they have different arrangements, you would say *Geometries*.

Answer (score 3):

Most dictionaries (such as http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/geometry) give the word as uncountable. In the original sentence, it is definitely not plural. The sentence is: *The geometry [of objects] **is** known*.

Answer (score -3):

From your sentences the second

> The geometry of the objects is known.

is definetely a valid one to use.

This is, because "geometry" is singular (according to [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Ageometry&oq=de&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0l4.959j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8), and a lot of other dictionaries and stuff), and we are probably not talking about different kinds of geometries (Euclidian, Hyperbolic, Elliptic, ...).

But the first sentence

> The geometry of the objects are known.

does not have a valid usage. It's because if you're talking about different kinds of geomerties, you have to put it in plural, like this:

> The geometries of the objects are known.